# Interpolate pandas dataframe around certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, interpolation

I have a dataset showing water levels over time and I want to plot all the data above a certain value (-0.75m in the example) in green and all the data below this value in orange. The problem I am facing is that whenever my data crosses over my value, the plotted line stops at that value and there are multiple gaps in my plot

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5dj5.png)

What I want to do is interpolate any time the data crosses this border so that my line will continue to the level of -0.75m in green and become orange from there on out.

I have tried to find out at which spots my data crosses this line and have inserted a row in my dataset with a y-value of -0.75 to later on interpolate the corresponding date in my dataframe but this has not worked yet so far.

Below is an example code where I make my own dataset and try to interpolate whenever I cross the value 2. This does seem to work for the trial dataset but not for my original data and the way in which I get the code to work seems very sketchy to me. Are there better ways of trying to achieve my goal?

```
d = {'x': ['2020-03-14', '2020-03-15', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-18', '2020-03-19'], 'y': [3, 4, 5, -1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index('x', inplace = True)

empty = {'y' : 2}
df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data=empty, index=[np.nan])

df_temp = df.copy()
df_temp.y -= 2

df_new = df.iloc[[0]]

# Add nan row in dataframe
for i in range(len(df_temp) -1):
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df.iloc[[i]]])
    if df_temp.y.iloc[i] * df_temp.y.iloc[i+1] < 0:
        df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df_empty])

# Polish new dataframe
df_new = df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df.iloc[[-1]]])
df_new = df_new.iloc[1:]

# set desired values as index
df_new.reset_index(inplace = True)
df_new.set_index('y',inplace = True)

# convert dates to numbers
df_new.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(df_new.iloc[:,0]))
# set negative numbers (the missing dates) to nan
df_new[df_new < 0] = np.nan

# interpolate nan values
df_new.iloc[:,0].interpolate(method = 'linear', inplace = True)
# convert back to datetime
df_new.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df_new.iloc[:,0])

# undo index change
df_new.reset_index(inplace = True)
df_new.set_index('index',inplace = True)

df.plot()
df_new.plot()
```

Comment: It really depends on what you want. How do you want the lines to be "connecting"? Do you wish to have green above -0.75 and yellow below? Or can they be green when crossing downwards and yellow crossing upwards?

Comment: What if you just try to plot the whole dataset in green and then you put on top of it the dataframe data `<-0.75` in orange color using `plt.subplots`? At that point the orange line should be on top of the green one when the values are `<0.75`, you should not be able to see the green one and the effect should be the desired one

Comment: @PrinsEdje80 I would indeed like to have green above -0.75 and yellow below. My idea was to insert a point on the line every time it crosses so that I could plot in green until this point and in orange afterwards.

Comment: @gioarma In that case the line connecting points let's say at -0.35 and -0.90 would be completely in green so part of the line below -0.75 would remain in green. I would like it to change colour the moment it passes the border of -0.75

Comment: @RutgerTauw In that case, you need to find the x coordinate at which it crosses the -0.75. That is some math you need to figure out. It basically comes down to solving [linear equations with two points](https://content.byui.edu/file/b8b83119-9acc-4a7b-bc84-efacf9043998/1/Math-2-11-2.html) for each pair of points where you cross the -0.75. Then solve it for y = -0.75 to get the x coordinate, add this x coordinate (with the -0.75) to both dataframes instead of the `np.nan` points.

Comment: @PrinsEdje80 That is what I was trying to do manually but my x-coordinate is a certain data and I was wondering if it is possible to let python interpolate these values for me in an easy manner.

Comment: AFAIK, you have to develop a method yourself. You can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) or [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) for all combination of points that cross the line (be sure to use only *linear* interpolation in that case, otherwise you get really weird values). That's I think the easiest way to "let python" do it for you.

Comment: @PrinsEdje80 Thanks for your help, I might then just have to continue with the method I was using haha

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have to iterate over data, using `NumPy` is faster than using `Pandas`.
See: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

Second, you said "This does seem to work for the trial dataset but not for my original data". In this case, you should provide original data for your question.

Anyway, here is a working code that uses `NumPy`. I am not sure that this will work for your original data.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Raw data
list_dtstr = ['2020-03-14', '2020-03-15', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-18', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-21', '2020-03-22']
list_value = [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, -1.0, 1.0, 4.0, -1.0, 3.0]

npdata = np.array([[datetime.datetime.strptime(dtstr, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp() for dtstr in list_dtstr], list_value])
npdata = npdata.transpose()

# Threshold value
threshold = 2.0

# Interpolate
for idx in range(len(npdata) - 1 , 0, -1):
    if (npdata[idx, 1] - threshold) * (npdata[idx - 1, 1] - threshold) < 0:
        interp_x = [npdata[idx - 1, 1], npdata[idx, 1]]
        interp_y = [npdata[idx - 1, 0], npdata[idx, 0]]
        
        # Sort interpolation data
        if interp_x[0] > interp_x[1]:
            interp_x = [interp_x[1], interp_x[0]]
            interp_y = [interp_y[1], interp_y[0]]
        
        # Interpolation
        dt_value = np.interp(threshold, interp_x, interp_y)
        
        # Insert interpolated data
        npdata = np.insert(npdata, idx, [dt_value, threshold], axis=0)

# Convert timestamp to datetime
npdata_new = np.array([[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(npdata[idx, 0]), npdata[idx, 1]] for idx in range(len(npdata))])

# Split data
npdata_above = npdata_new.copy()
npdata_below = npdata_new.copy()
for idx in range(len(npdata_new)):
    if npdata_new[idx, 1] > threshold:
        npdata_below[idx, 1] = None
    elif npdata_new[idx, 1] < threshold:
        npdata_above[idx, 1] = None

# Plot
plt.plot(npdata_above[:, 0], npdata_above[:, 1], c = 'green')
plt.plot(npdata_below[:, 0], npdata_below[:, 1], c = 'orange')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me. I realised that in my own original code my array was resorted after converting the times to floats. I added a new sort based on the converted times and that got it to work. Thank you for your help!